# newMeRequest's onCompleted method user is always null

Tags: android, facebook

When I make newMeRequest using Facebook Android SDK

```
Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
    @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
            if (user != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Logged in..." + user.getName());
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Logged in... but user==null");
            }
         }
     }).executeAsync();
```

Logcat says "Logged in.. but user==null"

what should I do?

Comment: You are sure the user is logged in?

Comment: I'm not. But response.getError() returns 'java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "graph.facebook.com": No address associated with hostname'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a parameter with specific fields :

```
Request request = Request.newMeRequest(currentSession, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
    ....
}

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
// REQUEST_FIELDS : id,name,email   
parameters.putString(FIELDS, REQUEST_FIELDS);
request.setParameters(parameters);
Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
```